# extending django cms - plugin class - understanding issue

Tags: django, django-cms

I am reading thru [Extending the CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_examples.html).

I have some issues in understanding some details:

I need to create a Plugin Class. e.g. `PollPlugin`.

```
class PollPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
  model = PollPluginModel                 # Model where data about this plugin is saved
  name = _("Poll Plugin")                 # Name of the plugin
  render_template = "polls/plugin.html"   # template to render the plugin with

  def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
      context.update({'instance':instance})
      return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PollPlugin) # register the plugin
```

my questions:

1. what is `instance` in this case?
2. what are goals of these two Plugin Classes? `PollPluginModel` and `PollPlugin`.
3. Difference between `Apphook` and `Plugin`

any answer is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-CMS Plugins can be a little tricky.

`instance` in this case would be an instance of `PollPlugin`.

`PollPlugin` serves as a "join" model that relates one or more instances of a `PollPluginModel` to a plugin instance (PollPlugin), which is then assigned to a placeholder on a page.

An "apphook" is a callback that tells Django-CMS that it needs to hand off processing of a view to additional user-specified URL pattern(s) in your app module.

A "plugin" is a model that can be assigned to a placeholder.

Comment: Thank you. My second thought was to email you if no answer comes in. Vielen Dank :) now I get it.

Comment: Bitte! Immer froh zu helfen.

Comment: hey Brandon, one more question. what does ``render`` do here?

Comment: `render` adds the plugin instance, placeholder and whatever else you need to add to the template context before the page is output.

Comment: Thanks, now i get it. but one more frage: how does Plugin find its apphook during rendering? i dont see any connection while defining both of them :(

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, a plugin doesn't know about AppHooks. They (AppHooks) just provide a mechanism to let you pass processing of the Page's view to your own view code. This is useful if you need to do something like process a form and render content from the CMS on the same page.

Comment: ah ok. but i just dont understand why custom plugin should return context data to template which is given with ``render_template``  whereas i can process the data from my own model and in my own view whose urls.py is registered in apphook.

Comment: Yes, of course you can - as a developer. If you're a content author, you don't have that ability. You're just someone who needs to add some content to a page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62672/discussion-between-doniyor-and-brandon).

Comment: now i understand the difference between apphook and plugin. .. or may be i dont :(. its a bit confusing: can plugin work without apphook? can apphook work without plugin?